# Having a guest on a local xbox join a party on MW3

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, xbox-network

If you start playing MW3, you can hit 'A' on a second controller to play with you split screen on live.

Also, you can hit 'Y' and invite friends, making a party through some games.

**Are you able to do these two things together?**

Moreso, I may want to do private party chat through Live versus in the game.

When starting the game back up, after joining in a party, the option to hit A was not there.

**Is there a way to be in an xbox live party and have a guest join in on the game?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be in a party while playing split-screen, but unless the second player has an Xbox Live account, they won't be able to participate in any of the voice chat options that Xbox Live offers.  You can plug a headset into their controller, but they won't hear the party/game chat audio, and their mic won't function.

If the options to join a party aren't on the same buttons in-game when you're playing split screen, you can always use the Xbox Guide button to access the party menu and start/join a party from that interface.

Note also that you have to have a second controller plugged in/turned on in order for the "Press A to Join" message to appear in most games (MW3 included).  There's nothing in MW3 or Xbox Live that prevents you from doing both at the same time.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't have the other controller on when I did that. But I did try this last night, and I know it worked if I set us up split screen then joined the party. And you are exactly right with the audio, she just shows up as being muted the whole time (so we turned the kinect mic on instead...but that disabled it for the both of us).